# How to install anacron in yocto (sumo)

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have installed `cronie`. It runs logrotate script monthly at midnight to compress the logs on device. But if device is not powered on at midnight, it does not run this script. What could be the possible solution for this? I guess, `anacron` will solve this issue. But I could not find this package in `openembedded-core`layer.

Comment: If you use systemd you don't need any additional daemons to do this: a systemd timer service with Persistent=true just works.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen : Thank you. I created simple test.timer which will run logrotate.service (/etc/logrotate.conf) every 15 minute. But logs are not compressed after 15 minutes. I used these commands. sudo systemctl enable test.timer, sudo systemctl start test.timer